# Logstash will not bind the UDP hostname of the syslog server

Tags: sockets, udp, logstash, syslog-ng

I have a centralized Syslog-ng server that outputs logs to port 10150 and when I do a UDP dump on that port I am able to see the logs being written to that port and IP.
On another server that contains the Logstash daemon on version 1.3+.  I am trying to read from UDP using input against that Syslog-ng server and I am getting this error:

```
<SocketError: bind: name or service not known>
```

For my Logstash daemon server I am using the following input:

```
input {
  udp {
    host => "syslog-ng.somedomain.com"
    port => 10510
    type => "syslog"
  }
}
```

I have my firewall between both of them wide open on that particular port.
Does anyone have any idea why Logstash 1.3+ is unable to read from that UDP port against that server?
Thanks in advance,
Cole

Comment: At face value, the error seems to suggest that `syslog-ng.somedomain.com` couldn't be resolved (have you tested that?). Some Googling turned up [LOGSTASH-840](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-840), in which one user encountered a similar error because the JVM was hogging the port.

Comment: I ended up routing syslog-ng to my Redis server and then fed logstash from Redis.  It is probably a better solution anyways since there a buffer if Elasticsearch goes down for any period of time.